# Why does aliasing int& allow for the creation of the non-function type const (int&)?

Tags: c++

Normally when working with constant to a reference one gets a compiler error, but not when aliasing or using templates. Why is this so?

```
int a = 5;
using my_t = int&;
my_t const b = a; //#1 OK 
int& const c = a; //#2 Compiler error
```

When running through the latest clang compiler (x86-64 clang (experimental P1144)), #1 gives me the warning:

> [x86-64 clang (experimental P1144) #1] warning: 'const' qualifier on reference type 'my_t' (aka 'int &') has no effect
>   [-Wignored-qualifiers]

and #2 gives me the error:

> [x86-64 clang (experimental P1144) #1] error: 'const' qualifier may not be applied to a reference.

x86-64 gcc (trunk) gives an error for #2 but nothing for #1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's just the rule. From [[dcl.ref]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref#1.sentence-4):

> Cv-qualified references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualifiers are introduced through the use of a *typedef-name* ([dcl.typedef], [temp.param]) or *decltype-specifier*, in which case the cv-qualifiers are ignored.

It's there to make it easier to code. `int& const` is obviously wrong, and there's no benefit to allowing it. `T const` could be valid for some `T`s, so it would be actively harmful to reject it when it's not - it's just easier to code if you allow it and ignore the invalid cv-qualifiers in those cases.

Comment: Is there a reason why "T const" is not disallowed when T is of reference type?

Comment: @DDaniel so templated code would not be affected when unessesary

Comment: @Slava: I'm failing to comprehend why it would be considered "harmful" or "unnecessary" to disallow for that case. Would not the fact that const is "ignored" be considered dangerous since I can change the value of such a variable even though it should be constant? Just curious as to the reasoning behind the rule.

Answer (score -3):

[image: Microsoft compiler]

It works in a Microsoft compiler.
Though it throws a warning
Warning C4227   anachronism used: qualifiers on reference are ignored

It is not prohibited by the standard, but it is considered ill-formated. So it is compiler defined.

Comment: It is prohibited by the standard.